# How to interpret this bit shift?

Tags: c

I am reading something and I don't understand the meaning of the bit shift that stated below but I think it is basically programming question. I am reading a file and see this 
`#define PIN_GEN   (((uint32_t)1)<<31)`, but I don't quite understand the meaning of `(((uint32_t)1)<<31)`. Could somebody tell me what is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((uint32_t)1)<<31` --> Make constant 1 of type `uint32_t` (32-bit unsigned with no padding) then shift left 31 places.  Same as

```
((uint32_t) 2147483648u)
```

The value is likely used as some sort of bit mask to indicate which bit to set.